# How to get the middle content to be position left and right inside of the border-radius?

Tags: html, css, web, scope

```css
.intro h1{
    font-family: 'Cambria';
        font-size: 16pt; 
        font: bold;
        text-align: left;
}

.intro p{ 
    
    font-family: 'Calibri';  
    font:italic;
    font-size: 12pt; 
    padding: 0px 690px 0px 20px;
    text-align: left;

}
.content{ 
    border: 2px solid; 
     -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px; 
}
#para1{
    padding: 0px 1050px 0px 20px; 
    
}
#para2{
    padding: 0px 1099px 0px 20px;
}

.username-label, .username-textbox, .password-label, .password-textbox {
   text-align:right; 
}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <link href="~/Styles/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title>Final Project</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/Home.js"></script>
        
        <div class="intro">

          <h1>Welcome to Cuyahoga Community College Student Services Online</h1>
            <p>Cuyahoga Community College recognizes students' rights to access personal and academic records
              in accordance with the Family Educational Rights and Privacy Act of 1974 (FERPA) as amended by Public Law 93-568.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
        <p id="para1">Already have an account with us? Returning users may log in by entering their site username and password. </p>
         <div class="username-label">Username: </div>
            <div class="username-textbox">
                <input class="existing username-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
       
            <div class="password-label">Password:</div>
            <div class="password-textbox">
                <input class="existing password-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
            <button id="button1">Log in</button>
            <hr />

            <p id="para2">New Users, please create a new account by providing us with some basic information.</p>
            <div class="Username-label1">Username: </div>
            <div class="username-textbox1">
                <input class="username-new-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="Password-label2">Password:</div>
            <div class="password-textbox2">
                <input class="password-new-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="Email-label3">Email:</div>
            <div class="email-textbox3">
                <input class="email-new-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="Repeat-Email-label4">Repeat Email Address:</div>
            <div class="repeat-email-textbox4">
                <input class="reenter-new-input-textbox" type="text" value="" />
            </div>
            <button id="button2">Create Account</button>

        </div>

        <footer>Cuyahoga Community College</footer>
        <footer>700 Carnegie Avenue, Cleveland, Ohio, 44115</footer>
    </body>

</html>
```

I am working on a web development project which consists of a login desktop screen that let's students at Tri-C (this is just for practice) enter their user name and password if they already have an existing account, but for the students who don't have an account, they can create an account. Also, I have not started to create any functionality on any of the buttons (that's coming later). I have been having trouble with trying to position the username and password labels and username and password textboxes to the right hand. I know I can use text-align property to get them to be on the right hand, but it doesn't do what I am trying to do in the picture. Here is my code so far and picture of what I am trying to accomplish.

[Here is my desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t1ET.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create new `div` elements inside the content div, one for the left side and one for the right side.  Then set `display: table-cell;` and `width: 50%`.  That should take care of it.

See a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/3urgq8ax/)

Edit: and get rid of that crazy padding!

Comment: @sn3ll-How do I get the textboxes to appear on the same line as each label? I tried display: inline, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @sn3ll-How can I get username and password labels and textboxes to come off from how it's looking now? That looks really unneat.

Comment: Use padding and/or margins